# yum command is not working Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, yum

My machine is running Fedora 20. The `yum` command was working last week, but now it is not working. When I try `yum update` or `yum clean all` it is not showing anything.

This is my yum.conf

```bash
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=3
```

This is my yum.repos.d files

```
fedora.repo                  google-talkplugin.repo       rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo  rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing.repo
fedora-updates.repo          rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo  rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide.repo
fedora-updates-testing.repo  rpmfusion-free.repo          rpmfusion-nonfree.repo
google-chrome.repo           rpmfusion-free-updates.repo  rpmfusion-nonfree-updates.repo
```

How can I debug it? What is the issue? I already checked the yum log. It is showing nothing.

Comment: what *exact* output is the command `yum clean all` returning? Have you tried disabling all of your non-fedora repos?

Comment: @warren all yum commands are not returning anything. Yes i checked it now. result is not changed.

Comment: Install the `strace` utility and run `strace yum`.

Comment: dumb q - but just as a sanity check :) ... you're running as `root`, right?

Comment: Do you get output with `yum --noplugins --help`?

Comment: sry. It had work after the restart.